# Having Tables inside NgFor with same height

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an ngFor which will iterate number of tables for me,In my case 3(not static) tables will be generated with the ngFor i am using, and inside the table I have rows that are to be generated, using another ngFor, but now, the problem, if my first is having less amount of data, say 2 rows of data, and my third table is having 6 rows of data, then the height of tables isn't constant. 
Expected Solution: All tables should be of equal height, if table 3 has 6 rows, then table 1 and table 2 should also have 6 rows, Lets keep the rows the static, i mean irrespective of data, each table should be able to show 6 rows. if table 2 has data for 2 rows then remaining 4 rows should be empty.

```
<div
class="shift-table"
[ngClass]="{ disablePreviousRecord: isPreviousWeekRecord }"
[attr.disabled]="isPreviousWeekRecord"
>
<div class="shift-name " *ngFor="let roster of rosterInfo">
<span>Shift - {{ roster.shiftName }}</span>

<table
  class="table scrollbar"
  id="customScrollDiv"
  style="background-color: white; color:#EBF4FF"
>
  <thead style="background-color: #9AA7C7;">
    <tr class="header">
      <th>
        Copy
      </th>
      <th>
        Person Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Role
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="text-black-50">
    <tr class="dataRow" *ngFor="let user of roster.userDetails">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" [disabled]="isPreviousWeekRecord" />
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ user.userId }}
      </td>
      <td>
        <span *ngFor="let role of user.roles; let i = index">
          {{ role }} {{ i === user.roles.length - 1 ? '' : ',' }}
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think it would be a good user experience to show empty rows. The best solution would be to keep height of the table same and do not add empty rows.

Comment: Yeah but that would add empty space without line seperators to my table

Comment: Right, I think that will make more sense to user instead of blank rows. Blank space means there are only 2 rows in that table, Blank rows will indicate that data is empty. Let say you have edit button on rows, then you will show edit icon in all rows or with rows that have data.

Comment: Here is the current look of my tables, i want them all with same height. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pwIFfx1Mv4UDGqWl55OyY9bgj1_bJjNj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, let say you add blank rows in first table, then it will also add checkboxes in front of it. This will create confusion for the user whether he can edit that empty row or not. So leaving empty space is better than adding empty rows.

Comment: Yeah cool, adding empty space is better option.